# Solving intersection points

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do you solve these functions for intersection points?
 $2^x = 3-x$

Do you use natural log first to get the x or do you need to use other approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = 2^x + x - 3$ has $f'(x) = 2^x\cdot \ln 2 + 1 > 0$ for any $x$, thus since $f(1) = 0$, $x = 1$ is the only solution to the equation. For if there were another solution $x > 1$ or $x < 1$, then for the first case, apply Rolle's theorem on the interval $[1,x]$ for the differentiable  function $f$ above, there is a number $ c\in (1,x)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$ but this can't happen. Thus the only intersection point is: $(1,2)$.

Comment: so the intersection points are 0 and 1?

Comment: Its $x = 1$, and the point of intersection is $(1,2)$.

Comment: oh okay because in my book it says its 0 and 1 but I wasnt sure how they got 1. It says hint: find intersection points by inspection

Comment: so the algebra way is to use the derivative?

Comment: I think so and its the most efficient way beside using graph.